# django db migration failed with postgres

Tags: django, postgresql

I made some changes to my models and then ran a

python manage.py makemigrations
   python manage.py migrate

and I got this traceback:

```
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: staticfiles, messages
  Apply all migrations: sessions, admin, study, auth, quiz, contenttypes, main
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
  Installing custom SQL...
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying quiz.0013_auto_20151005_0644...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 393, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 444, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 222, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 110, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(states[migration], migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 154, in apply_migration
    self.recorder.record_applied(migration.app_label, migration.name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 67, in record_applied
    self.migration_qs.create(app=app, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 348, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 734, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 762, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 846, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 885, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 127, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 920, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 974, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 97, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "django_migrations_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(27) already exists.
```

I didn't know quite how to interpret the error that the primary key already exists. Strangely enough it added the field into the database because I was seeing it output on my site and when I ran a shell I could see that the fields were added and the default data 'that I chose' was populated.

I decided to run the migration again to see if it would pass after a second time and I got a different traceback...

```
   Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: staticfiles, messages
  Apply all migrations: sessions, admin, study, auth, quiz, contenttypes, main
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
  Installing custom SQL...
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying quiz.0013_auto_20151005_0644...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 393, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 444, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 222, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 110, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(states[migration], migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 148, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 115, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 62, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 398, in add_field
    self.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 111, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 97, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "lang1_back_to_choice" of relation "quiz_langpairinstructions" already exists
```

Now if I try it again I will always get the second traceback. I am wondering what I should do so I can make migrations in the futures. Why am I getting this error if everything appears to have gone smoothly in the db itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I overlooked the name of the 'django_migrations_pkey' column and I didn't realize that was in the database. Somehow django was one step behind the actual database and trying to use the primary key (pk=27) instead of the number it was actually on (which should have been 28)

I was unsure about how to change this from within django so instead I just deleted the last column from the database so it was one primary key shorter and on track with django and it started working just fine.

Comment: can you also add the comand you used to delete the last column and what table should it be deleted. That can make your answers extremely useful for new developers in the feild like myself.

Answer (score 27):

There is another way. Since you know the last `id` value in `django_migrations` table, say it is 100. Then, you need to do this:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE django_migrations_id_seq RESTART WITH 101;
```

Answer (score 3):

I got this error after I had previously manually tinkered with the django migrations tables entries (after some previously dodgy migrations were added then removed).

This left the django_migrations IDs out of order (so to speak) with the default position of the entry in the django_migrations table.

The issue is that django takes the ID of the last entry and +1 to create a new entry (in table below: 197 + 1 = 198), however as you can see Key (id)=(198) already exists in the table.

```
187 | foo_app             | 0016_auto_20161220_2332                     | 2017-01-06 05:22:07.666172+00
198 | bar_app             | 0004_auto_20160423_2122                     | 2017-01-13 05:38:31.922738+00
197 | baz_app             | 0013_auto_20170203_2311                     | 2017-02-08 18:50:22.70143+00
```

As you can see the numbers for the primary key on the left are out of order.
What I did was manually delete the out of order entries in the django_migration then re-add them.

```
DELETE from django_migrations where name = '0004_auto_20160423_2122';
DELETE from django_migrations where name = '0013_auto_20170203_2311';

INSERT INTO django_migrations VALUES (188, 'baz_app', '0013_auto_20170203_2311', date());
INSERT INTO django_migrations VALUES (189, 'bar_app', '0004_auto_20160423_2122', date());
```

Also of note is that the migration that I was initially trying to add 'new_app, '0002_auto_00000000_1111' actually modified the new_app table in postgres, however the django_migrations table didn't get updated.

So the second time I tried to re-run the migration 0002_auto_00000000_1111  I got the error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "new_app_field" of relation "new_app_new" already exists
```

My solution above fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Simply reindexing the django_migrations table worked for me.

Follow these steps in  your terminal

Change user to root

```
$ sudo su
```

So that you can then then change user to postgres

```
$ su postgres
```

Open postgres terminal client with your db selected

```
$ psql name_of_your_db
```

In the postgres client issue the following command

```
REINDEX TABLE django_migrations;
```

And then quit the postgres client

```
\q
```

Comment: From within my database gui I selected the option to reindex and this is a link to the documentation for postgres: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/sql-reindex.html