# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "iranian_citi

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I am a django developer, I want to use iranian cities library, but when I run this command

> py manage.py generate_city

this error got:

```
    > (myenv) D:\myproject\math\maths>py manage.py generate_city
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\myproject\math\myenv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "iranian_cities_ostan_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\myproject\math\maths\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\myproject\math\maths\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "D:\myproject\math\myenv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "D:\myproject\math\myenv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "D:\myproject\math\myenv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "D:\myproject\math\myenv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 458, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\myproject\math\myenv\Lib\site-packages\iranian_cities\management\commands\generate_city.py", line 128, in handle
    self.generate_ostan(ostan_data_path)
  File "D:\myproject\math\myenv\Lib\site-packages\iranian_cities\management\commands\generate_city.py", line 37, in generate_ostan     
    Ostan.objects.bulk_create(ostan_objs)
  File "D:\myproject\math\myenv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\myproject\math\myenv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 786, in bulk_create
    returned_columns = self._batched_insert(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\myproject\math\myenv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1831, in _batched_insert
    self._insert(
  File "D:\myproject\math\myenv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1805, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\myproject\math\myenv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1822, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\myproject\math\myenv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 102, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\myproject\math\myenv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\myproject\math\myenv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\myproject\math\myenv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "D:\myproject\math\myenv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "D:\myproject\math\myenv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "iranian_cities_ostan_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.
```

I add the iranian_cities to the ISTALLED_APPS in my settings.py in my django project and I intsall the library from the pip, I don't know that what is wrong?...
If you know it, please answer.
What should I do?
Please help me...

Comment: Read the error message `DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.`. The table already has data in it and the new data duplicates that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "django\_migrations\_pkey"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51071385/django-db-utils-integrityerror-duplicate-key-value-violates-unique-constraint)